# Force Component Rerender in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app that fetches a list of todos from the backend, displays them in a list, and offers you a button to add a new one.

I notice that the newly added to do will only appear in the list AFTER I refresh the page (e.g. after it fetches from the backend). I'd like to force the component to re-render with the newly added to do, ideally without a backend call. How can I do that?

Component AFTER I've hit "add"  - text stays in the box, does not appear in the list
[image]

Page AFTER I've hit add and refreshed the page - appears below - I'd like this behavior to happen without a manual refresh
[image]

App.tsx

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import './App.css';
import APIHelper from "./APIHelper";

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTodoAndSetTodos = async () => {
      const todos = await APIHelper.getAllTodos()
      setTodos(todos)
    }
    fetchTodoAndSetTodos()
  }, [])

  const createTodo = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const newTodo = await APIHelper.createTodo(todo)
    // @ts-ignore
    setTodos([...todos, newTodo])
  }

  return (
          <div className="App">
            <div>
              <input
                      id="todo-input"
                      type="text"
                      value={todo}
                      onChange={({target}) => setTodo(target.value)}
              />
              <button type="button" onClick={createTodo}>
                Add
              </button>
            </div>
            <ul>
              {todos.map(({_id, task, completed}, i) => (
                      <li
                              key={i}
                              className={completed ? "completed" : ""}
                      > {task}
                      </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

APIHelper.js

```
import axios from "axios"

const API_URL_GET = "http://localhost:8080/"
const API_URL_CREATE = "http://localhost:8080/create"

async function createTodo(task) {
    const { data: newTodo } = await axios.post(API_URL_CREATE, {
        task,
    })
    return newTodo
}

async function getAllTodos() {
    const { data: todos } = await axios.get(API_URL_GET)
    return todos
}
export default { createTodo, getAllTodos }



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuYUK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDne4.png
```

Comment: Chan you show us what is in the `APIHelper.createTodo`?

Comment: What is the current behavior? It looks like it should only display the latest todo in the list.

Comment: @giotskhada I put the current behavior in the screenshots - what can I add that is not clear?

Comment: What happens if there are multiple todos in the list already and you try to add a new one?

Comment: Here's why I'm asking: `setTodos([...todos, newTodo])` this will always put just the new todo in the todos list, because the function is created as a `const` when `todos` is empty. Instead you should use the previous state like so `setTodos(todos => [...todos, newTodo])`

Comment: Check out my answer. I guess the `newTodo ` is the wrong object.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `createTodo` function, you'll need to reset your `todo` state.
Which means setting it to an empty string again:

```js
const createTodo = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
    // ...
    setTodo(''); // Here
}
```

Comment: That successfully clears the box after typing, but the refresh behavior still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems like that `APIHelper.createTodo`returns a wrong object. The list item is at the screen, but has no `task`property.
As mentioned above, **Try to prevent forceUpdate() the component.**

```
async function createTodo(task) {
    const { data: newTodo } = await axios.post(API_URL_CREATE, {
        task,
    });
    // check this newTodo value
    return newTodo
}
```

To reset the `input`field, `setTodo("")`to an empty string

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should avoid this but still here you go you can using forceUpdate

In your component, you can call `this.forceUpdate()` to force a rerender.

Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html